# Java 2D mixed array of enum and String

Tags: java, arrays, string, enums

I have an enum class as follows:

```
public enum ProductCategory {
    ELECTRONICS,
    ACCESSORIES,
    GROCERY,
    CLOTHING,
    HOMELIVING
}
```

I would like to implement a 2D mixed array that stores mixed datatype `String` and the `enum` as well:

```
Object[][] ProductList2 = {
    {"Smartwatch", ProductCategory.ACCESSORIES},
    {"Powerbank", ProductCategory.ELECTRONICS},
    {"Vacuum cleaner", ProductCategory.HOMELIVING}
};
```

The first `column` will be storing `String` data type whereas the second `column` stores the `enum` data type. However, if i run the following code:

```
ProductList[i][1].getClass();
```

The code returns that the datatype of the stored value is of `class java.lang.String` type. How do I store the `enum` as it is? Thank you!

Comment: Cant you use `Map<String,ProductCategory>` for that ?

Comment: You are showing us how you initialized `ProductList2` array, but later you are using `ProductList` (without `2` suffix). Is that typo in question, or in your real code?

Comment: Don't use this setup. It'll be inefficient and not type safe. Go with Maps or MultiMaps depending on how you want to consume these later.

Comment: @Pshemo sorry its typo..

Comment: @Antoniossss, @Amin J, i'm not really familiar with the ``Map`` concept, thanks for you guys suggestions. I will try study about it.

Comment: So I am assuming that this is typo in your real code. When I'm printing result of `ProductList2[0][1].getClass().getSimpleName()` I am seeing `ProductCategory` as expected. Voting to close as typo/problem can't be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your code returns ProductCategory as expected. java.lang.String will be returned when ProductList2[i][0] is written instead of ProductList2[i][1].

You want a collection that contains String-ProductCategory pairs to identify an element with the help of keys (in this example, key can be String type). For this purpose using Object array is not recommended. The reason being that you can store literally any type of object inside this array, be it String, ProductCategory, any array or even an instance Object itself.

So an ideal alternative for your task would be java.util.Map interface. This interface has functionalities of storing and retrieving key-value pairs in efficient way. Here is the map api to get you started. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html The most common classes that implement this interface for the purpose similar to yours is java.util.HashMap. This collection has very cool features. You can't store duplicate key value. If you have String as your key type, an attempt to store an element having already existing key, the old element will be replaced by newer one. Many more features have been introduced. I would recommend you to study it and try to do your task using this collection.